# How to get QueryString value in javascript on Partial view in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In my scenario, i need to get QueryString value on page load on Partial view in MVC
   my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var industries = '@Request.QueryString["industries"]';
    alert(industries);
}); 

</script>
```

When i rendering QueryString value that time it is working fine but in  Javascript it's not working.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript). Also keep the scripts in the main view as much as you can instead of within partial views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a work around:

Make Hidden Feild and put the QS in it, then get the value using jquery selector.

```
  <input type='hidden' value='@Request.QueryString["industries"]' id='HdnIndustries' />

  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var industries = $("#HdnIndustries").val();
    alert(industries);
  }); 

  </script>
```